# sending a structure from C server to java (android) client

Tags: android, c, sockets, client

I have a C server which sends the below structure to the client upon a successful connection and relevant query to populate the structure.

```
 #pragma pack(push)
 typedef struct{
  int a[5];
  char b[5][20];
  char title[5][50];
   }rinfo;
 #pragma pack(pop)
```

So i am able to successfully send this structure to a C client which is able to read it properly. Now if i want to do the same for a Java client (i'm weak in java) then I feel i should define a class of the same members like

```
  Class rinfo {
  //the above members
    }
```

but then how do i read the structure from the java socket? For normal messages I use

```
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

where socket is my socket definition. How should i change the above statement to read the structure being passed by my C server. Also, are there any complications involved? Anything to do with byte order conversions? I'm a newbie to java programming.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use a JSON/XML as a mechanism to pack the data. If you put if you put it in a ByteArray, then you need to split them according to the sizes and if the size varies, then you will find it difficult and exceptions are thrown.

Going further, you can use the BufferedReader to read the data in Bytes and then convert them to string to get the full data.

Many samples to read are available on the web for doing this.

Comment: Can for which you need a link, JSON formating? BufferedReader? Reading data ?

Comment: XML formatting and using BufferedReader for reading the formatted data

Comment: See this link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-dataAndroid/?ca=drs-

Comment: so the basic idea is that i have to convert the things which i want my structure to pass as an XML string and then pass it?

Comment: Yes... I would suggest use the JSON rather than XML, it is simple to parse and get the data data out also.